# Regular expression with URL extraction

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url

I am using C# for this project and basically what I need is a way to make plain text into HTML, I found a regular expression (I think on Stack Overflow actually) for converting links in the text to anchor links in HTML, it looks like this:

```
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match match in mactches)
        {
            output = output.Replace(match.Value, String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{0}</a>", match.Value));
        }
```

It works great, however I found a flaw in that it doesn't consider a dash (-) as part of the URL, so when it hits the first dash it closes the anchor tag.
So I obviously need to include the dash somehow in the regular expression, but the problem is that I have absolutely no clue about RegEx and it just looks like Russian to me. 
Does anyone have an idea what small edit I need to make to the RegEx expression to make it include a dash as allowed characters in the URL?

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL it doesn't match? My tests show that it does..

Comment: Also, you have `matches` spelled wrong :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `@"https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?"`

I added a dash to the second character class (the part in square brackets) to match dashes in the part of the URL that is not the domain name.

Comment: +1. As simple as that. I didn't realise the OP was having issues with directories.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot that fixed it.
Problem was with URLs with dashes in the "pretty" SEO links, such as this: http://www.yourdomain.com/this-pretty-link-didnt-work-before-now-it-does

Answer (score 0):

I use this one which supports the `ftp` and `file` schemes as well as `http`:

```
@"\b((https?|ftp|file)://|(www|ftp)\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;\(\)]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]"
```

It will recognise a URL that contain parameters delimited by `&` like this:

http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=7400904n&tag=re1.channel

The original is at [Extract URLs from a text (Regex)](http://www.datavoila.com/projects/text/extract-urls-from-a-text-regex.html).  I modified it slightly to recognise a URL that contains parentheses like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686722(v=VS.85).aspx

You need to specify `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` with this regex though of course you could simplify by replacing `A-Z` with `\w`.